# Как получить номер юникод символа из std::string

Tags: c++, строки, utf-8

У меня есть переменная типа `std::string`. Мне нужно получить текст в символах в юникода. Как это можно сделать? Всё что нагуглил - это использование `codecvt` через `wstring_convert` который помечен как устаревший и у меня с ним код просто не компилируется.
Сам код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

void print(const std::u16string& str)
{
    for(auto c: str)
       std::cout << (int) c << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    std::string a{"П"};
    std::u16string u16(a.begin(), a.end());
    print(u16);

    return 0;
}
```

Так выводится:

```
65488
65439
```

Должно быть `1055`.

Если я сразу передаю u16string, то всё отображается верно. Как из обычного `std::string` можно переконвертировать?

Comment: Нашёл всё таки решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148403/utf8-to-from-wide-char-conversion-in-stl. В ответ не добавляю. Может подскажете для решения моей задачи есть ли решение лучше

Comment: Если вам нужно перевести из utf-8 в unicode, то это очень просто. Количество подряд идущих единичных бит в первом байте говорят в скольких байтах закодирован символ (помещаете в перменную `n`). Оставшиеся биты помещаете в переменную (скажем, `v`). Затем в цикле `for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) v = (v << 6) | (str[i] & 0x3f);` получаете свой unicode / (вообще, это количество байт можно получить, использовав старшие 5 бит первого байта как индекс в таблице длин utf-8 символов, поскольку современный utf-8 ограничен 4-мя байтами. Ну и не забудьте, что если первый байт меньше 128, то это обычный ascii)

Comment: @avp спасибо. Благодаря вашему комментарию Я понял что делается в функциях в ссылке которую я скинул. Мне вообще это нужно чтобы находить глифы по чар коду в freetype. Думаю тогда оставлю текущий вариант. Конверт в u16 и далее итерация по каждому символу